# Samba mount error(6): No such device or address - but device exists

Tags: virtualbox, cifs

I am running Virtualbox on a Windows 8.1 host, and Debian guest.

I have a folder on Windows shared, and want to mount it with cifs on the guest, as follows:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.12/Users/Paul/Documents/code_stash /mnt/pc -o user=Paul,password=password
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

This is in dmesg and syslog also. I am certain that Users/Paul/Documents/code_stash exists on Windows and is shared, and also that /mnt/pc exists.

Any suggestions or insights please into what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: In my case, I was putting a `c\$` instead of `c$` for my admin share. There is no escaping in `fstab`, only in `auto.direct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.12/Users/Paul/Documents/code_stash /mnt/pc -o username=Paul,password=password
```

Some other stuff that has foiled me:

Make sure smbd and nmbd are both running.

Make sure your linux user has access to the `/mnt/pc` share.

Make sure your linux user is in the "sambashare" group (may be different on your distro).

Make sure your Windows user has permissions to access the "Users" share on the Windows machine.

Troubleshoot permissions by running the command as root.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually windows firewall was blocking it- but all the above are valid!

Comment: I had similar issue and adding to options `ver=1.0` helped me